# Getting System.IO.FileNotFoundException and "Error restoring package" for System.Threading.Thread

Tags: sql, uwp, xamarin.forms

I am developing a cross platform app for Android and Windows with Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin Forms.

When I build the project I have no problems. However, if I run the app on Windows and I try to connect to the database, I get the following exception:

```
"System.IO.FileNotFoundException" in System.Data.SqlClient.dll ("Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Thread, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. System could not specific file.") System.IO.FileNotFoundException
```

I tried to install the `System.Threading.Thread` NuGet package, but I got this error message:

```
Error restoring package
```

Here is the code I used that worked with the `SqlConnection` previously:

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    DisplayAlert("estado", "estado: " + conn.State, "ok");
}
catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException eo)
{
    DisplayAlert("estado", "ERROR1!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n" + eo.Message, "ok");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    DisplayAlert("estado", "ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n"+ ex.Message, "ok");
}
```

Comment: Is there perphaps more information in the innerexception of the error?

Comment: no, this is all information of the exception:                                                       "System.IO.FileNotFoundException" in System.Data.SqlClient.dll ("Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Thread, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. System could not specific file.") System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Comment: What xamarin version are you using currently? I Found some bugs about this matter but they are rsolved in the newest Xamarin version

Comment: Have you tried to Restore Nuget Packages?

Comment: my version of xamarin is 2.3.4.247 in visual studio 2015, is the last stable version. I can update to 2.3.5.256-pre6, but is preliminar.

Comment: when i tried to install system.threading.thread, I see this errors: 
System.Threading.Thread 4.0.0 proporciona un ensamblado de referencia en tiempo de compilación para System.Threading.Thread en UAP,Version=v10.0, pero no hay un ensamblado en tiempo de ejecución compatible con win10-arm.
Uno o más paquetes no son compatibles con UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
Uno o más paquetes no son compatibles con UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
No se pudo restaurar el paquete para 'sql.UWP'.
Error al restaurar el paquete. Revirtiendo los cambios del paquete para 'sql.UWP'.

Comment: I could not  reproduce your issue with the segment code. Could you share a simple project?

Comment: On android this project are good, however on UWP(windows) jump exception, this is my project:      https://www.mediafire.com/?xjtspgytjjppazp